# codeunits dart to Encoding.Unicode C#

Tags: c#, dart

I have a socket TCP server write in C#. The client request are Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).

I have a client program write in dart that send String codeUnits via Socket.add command.

My problem is that in C# Encoding.Unicode.GetString read 2 bytes per characters...

My question is how in can read codeUnits from dart to Unicode C# and conversely?

```
String str = '3a487186711dc218';
```

in Dart:

```
str.codeUnits = [51, 97, 52, 56, 55, 49, 56, 54, 55, 49, 49, 100, 99, 50, 49, 56];
```

in C#:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str) = [51, 0, 97, 0, 52, 0, 56, 0, 55, 0, 49, 0, 56, 0, 54, 0, 55, 0, 49, 0, 49, 0, 100, 0, 99, 0, 50, 0, 49, 56]
```

Comment: Is Dart UTF-8 or UTF-16LE (as Encoding.Unicode is)?

Comment: @John Dart is [UTF-16](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_runes.htm)

Comment: Is there a way to send codeUnits as Unicode C#? I have test with add a 0 between codeUnits but i am sure is not the good solution...

Comment: @NicolasG The code units are not bytes, but UTF-16 codepoints and thus 16-bits long. To get the codeunits do `str.Select(ch => (int)ch).ToArray()`, which will return an array of ints, not an array of bytes and conversely `var str = new string(codeUnits.Select(x => (char)x).ToArray())`.

Comment: @ckuri Thx for your time. I agree with you. I can't send codeUnits to my Tcp server because i have to convert string to byte[]. This will work for ASCII char but not for other like 汉语. I am testing a package for flutter (dart) name utf. I will come back after

Comment: Can you not just convert the Dart string into UTF-8 and send the bytes? You can use the Utf8Encoder class from dart:convert to get a list of bytes. Or do you really need to have the text send as UTF-16?

Comment: @julemand101 Thx but no. I don't want to modify my server side app.UTF-8 is multibyte character encoding. Characters can have 1 to 6 bytes (some of them may be not required right now).

UTF-32 each characters have 4 bytes a characters.

UTF-16 uses 16 bits for each character and it represents only part of Unicode characters called BMP (for all practical purposes its enough). Java, C# and Dart uses this encoding in its strings if i am right.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i think the problem is solved.

As the codeunits in dart is Utf16 (16-bits) i can convert each in 2 bytes array :

```
List<int> convertCodeUnitsToUnicodeByteArray(List<int> codeUnits) {
  ByteBuffer buffer = new Uint8List(codeUnits.length*2).buffer;
  ByteData bdata = new ByteData.view(buffer);
  int pos = 0;
  for(int val in codeUnits) {                
    bdata.setInt16(pos, val, Endian.little);
    pos += 2;
  }
  return bdata.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Now from Tcp socket C# i get the String send by my flutter application correctly.